# How to re include php script or run few times without forking / or speed up forking

Tags: php, websocket

When WebSocket server get message it should run script by path that it gets.

Now I use this scheme:

In WebsocketDaemon:

```
protected function onMessage($connectionId, $data, $type) {
    if (!strlen($data) || !$this->checkFlood($connectionId))
        return;

    $dataArg = base64_encode($this->getRepackData($connectionId, $data));
    $response = shell_exec('php cli/runthroughwebsocket.php '.$dataArg);

    $this->sendPacketToClient($connectionId, $response);
}
```

runthroughwebsocket.php:

```
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli')
    return;
chdir(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/..');

function setData($packet) {
    $GLOBALS['ws'] = true;
    $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $packet->url;
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = $packet->agent;
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $packet->ip;
    foreach ($packet->cookie as $key => $cookie)
        $_COOKIE[$key] = $cookie;
}

if (empty($argv[1]))
    return;

$packet = json_decode(base64_decode($argv[1]));
setData($packet);

require_once 'index.php';
```

And it runs like through browser but with parameters that I need. So - it works. But SLOW. It takes few seconds. Even AJAX working faster. I suppose it because of "shell_exec". If not use "shell_exec" and run script by "include" - it fast like bullet, but after second "onMessage" it will write "Cannot redeclare class". And I don't know how to run script in another way. With "require_once" troubles too.
Do you have any advice?

**UPDATE:**

So, I understand that I can't run other scripts in websocket thread. The problem is that my scripts uses global variables like $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, etc. And I can't replace it to local variables. It means that I can't work with users without fork... :-(
Is "shell_exec" the fastest (or right) way?

**UPDATE again:**

I find out that problem is in that line "shell_exec('**php** ". It runs php.exe process about 2 seconds. How I can it speed up?

**I solve the problem!**

The problem was in browcap.ini file. Because of it php.exe loads too slow.
No more need in re include. "exec()" works fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Move the class to its own class file, where ever you need access to it call it with require_once then instantiate an instance.

After that you can do your iterations through what is needed because you have your object to work with and you are just reusing the object instead of redeclaring the whole class.

Update:

classfile.php

```
class classname {

    // class methods here.

}
```

index.php

```
require_once 'classfile.php';
$classobject = new classname;

// You want to do your actions/loops etc here.
```

Basically include/require the class file rather than the other way around.

Comment: Every file that I include/require is a class (only cli (shell) files without class). And when I do "require_once" it not writes an error, but there is a troubles. When I turn off my database the script answers with message about that. But when I turn on my database script still answer that database is still off...

Comment: I don't fully understand "requre_once" work, but when script do "new $class()" again it respond not actual state.

Comment: Okay, so you already have it "working" with require once (basically it just make sure the file is not included into the script again preventing duplication errors). The problem then is not as you initially stated, you will need to update your question with the new information and provide the code that you believe is breaking.